# mysqldump - how to use correlated nested query in where clause

Tags: mysql

I would like to use mysqldump to dump some selected rows from a table. However, to select the rows I need I would need to use a query that contains a correlated nested query. As a plain query, I would select the rows like this:

```
select type, version, dataimage
from firmware fw
where version = (select MAX(version) from firmware where type = fw.type)
```

In the inner query I'm referring to the outer table by the alias "fw". How could I formulate this to the where clause of mysqldump? I don't know how I could refer to the outer table from the nested query. Is it even possible?

Would be great if there is some "magical alias" that I could use in the nested query to refer to the outer table. Tried to read the documentation for the where clause, but didn't see any mention of nested queries.

Comment: Try this :mysqldump --user=<username> --password=<password> --host=<hostname> --where="version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM firmware f WHERE f.type = firmware.type)" <database_name> firmware --no-create-info > firmware_dump.sql

Comment: @HiteshPadhara. That will not work as the `f.type = firmware.type` will always be evaluated as true as `f` and `firmware` will point to same table.

Comment: If you want to use mysqldump, the easiest way is to select the rows to a new table and dump that table.

Comment: @slaakso that might make sense. Then the INSERT statements would contain a wrong table name, but that could be fixed by doing text search&replace, I guess.